# Look for software that can convert sql (mysql) to erd

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to have an ER Diagarm in phpmyadmin, however, its graph is not up to my expectation, the graph has no relationship indicator (1-1) (1-m) etc at all.

So i am wondering whether there is a software that can transfer the sql/ any kind of file exported from phpmyadmin to a diagarm? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have visio professional you can use the database reverse engineer feature on this.  It will work with pretty much anything that supports ODBC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or Navicat for MySQL (http://navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_overview.html)